# How to render page elements from hook_form_alter() drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6

I need to render contact form field elements using `form_alter` function.

When I print `$content` variable in tpl file, the contact form loads entirely, instead of that I need to render fields separately like `drupal_render(drupal_get_form(form['name']))`.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, you can refer to /modules/node/node.tpl.php as an example. Here is a code snippet in the file:

```
<div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
  <?php
    // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
    hide($content['comments']);
    hide($content['links']);
    print render($content);
  ?>
</div>

<?php print render($content['links']); ?>

<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
```

I'm not sure if there is difference in Drupal 6, but you can try.